# How does this egrep command find the longest line in a file?

Tags: command-line, grep, regex

I found a command line that uses [`egrep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/egrep.1.html) to find the longest line in a text file, but I don't quite understand all of the syntax nor how it works.

With a better grasp on the technique, I may be able to adjust it for other tasks.

I understand `egrep` and `-n`, but I don't follow the use of `^.` and the two `$` characters.

Could someone break down the following command?

```
egrep -n "^.{$(wc -L < filename)}$" filename
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Full Command:** `egrep -n "^.{$(wc -L < filename)}$" filename`

**Breakdown:**

`egrep` = The `egrep` program, which searches for lines which match a pattern and prints them.  (similar to `grep`).  Equivalent to `grep -E` which interprets the thing in quotes as an extended regular expression pattern.

`-n` = egrep argument to state the line number.

`$(wc -L < filename)` - `wc` is a word counter program and prints the number of new lines and stuff in the file.  `-L` is the `wc` max line length argument.  `< filename` is the command to pass the full content of the specified `filename` file into `wc`.  `$(  )` is a Bashism (something that is related to the `bash` program and scripting language) and is a way to say "Process the command in here, then put the output in place of this entire string.  The rest of that command appears to be part of regular expressions, plus the input passed into the string, ultimately with this just being the pattern that `egrep` matches on.

`"^.{`...`}$"` = The `"` is just a way to pass that pattern to `egrep` without characters in it being interpteted as Bash codes.  The rest of this is a [***regular expression***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) pattern.  Regex is something everyone should know.  I use [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/) to help me learn and understand regex, and to build regex patterns.  To break this down, `^` is an anchor and indicates that it matches the beginning of the string.  `.` indicates any character except a line break before the next argument.  `{` and `}` indicate actual `{` and `}` characters in the output, according to RegExr.  The `$` at the end is an anchor to indicate the end of the string.